# How to see Hibernate into files categories on Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, ide, categories

I'm currently trying to use Hibernate in a java project on Netbeans IDE.
Unfortunatly i'm not able to see "Hibernate" into files category while creating one..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8HNA.jpg

Please help i'm getting crazy..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just download and run NetBeans 10.0 it isn't just the creation of Hibernate files that is unavailable. There is no Java EE functionality, nor the ability to create web applications. You don't mention which version of NetBeans you are using, but assuming it's the latest version (10.0), you just need to install some plug-ins:

- Select **Tools > Plugins > Settings** and you should see an entry named **NetBeans 8.2 Plugin Portal** in the list of **Update Centers** on the left of the window:
- Check that entry, select **Every Startup** from the **Check Interval** drop list, click **Close** and restart NetBeans.

  [image: plugin1]
- After the restart select **Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins**. Select all of the entries in the list with a Category of **HTML5**, **Java SE**, **Java Web and EE** and **Payara** and click **Install** to install those plugins:

  [image: plugin2]
- After restarting NetBeans, verify that the plugins have been properly installed. Use the project wizard to create a web application: **File> New Project > Java Web > Web Application**.
- During the creation of the web project you should be invited to use the Hibernate framework:

  [image: plugin3]
- Once the project has been created, select **File > New File...** to add a file to the project. In the **New File** window enter **Hibernate** in the **Filter** field and NetBeans should list the different **File Types** for Hibernate:

  [image: plugin4]

Notes

- You don't need to install all of those plugin options if you are only using Hibernate, but they are reasonable defaults for general web development with NetBeans. Feel free not to check any of the proposed options that you definitely don't want/need.
- While restarting NetBeans after installing the plugins I got the **Warning** screen shown below. I just clicked **Disable Modules and Continue** button.

  [image: plugin5]

Comment: Can we please continue in chat room. I seriously need help. I did exactly what you said. But there's no 'Hibernate' option for me.

Comment: @Tanzeel [1] If you have a problem then please post a new question. That way your issue is visible to the entire community. Be sure to link to this question, making it clear that it did not solve your problem to avoid the risk of yours being closed as a duplicate. [2] Chat on SO is not intended for the resolution of user problems for which there is no question. [3] Without knowing your exact problem, a potential solution is to try using a more recent version of NetBeans than 10.0. You don't have to unistall your existing installation of NetBeans to do that. Is that feasible?