# How to add Hibernate plugin in NetBeans 12.4

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans

First thing that I checked was this question:

[How to see Hibernate into files categories on Netbeans IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54725338/how-to-see-hibernate-into-files-categories-on-netbeans-ide)

I followed each and every step very carefully but still no luck. My question is almost same as above but none of the solutions is working for me. I still can't see `Hibernate` category here. I have to have it for creating `hibernate.conf.xml`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

To avoid pasting multiple screenshots and going back and forth, I've recorded one video. Please watch my problem [here](https://youtu.be/m65L_KA-i5o). It's hardly a 2 min video. I've explained everything in it. I really need help. Please chime in.

Comment: Please watch this video to see the problem live: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m65L_KA-i5o&ab_channel=TanzeelMirza

Comment: Also I uninstalled NetBeans completely from my machine and installed again and repeated all the steps but no luck.